# mail function not working in php

Tags: php

When I send mail to "gatbajrang@gmail.com", it's working fine. But when I change email address "gatbajrang@gmail.com"  to "bajrang.lal@sunarctechnologies.com" then the mail has not been send, I could not find what is the error here. Both email address are correct. And always printing the message line under if condition.

I have also checked mail in trash,spam etc.

```
//$email_id = "gatbajrang@gmail.com"; 
$email_id = "bajrang.lal@sunarctechnologies.com";
$subject = "New Suggestion Posted. Waiting for approval.";
$mail_msg="Hello Admin,<br><br>New Suggestion Posted. Waiting for approval.<br><br>";  

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Tata NYK <gatbajrang@gmail.com>"; 
$headers .= "Organization: Tata NYK\r\n"; 
if(mail($email_id,$subject,$mail_msg))
  echo "mail sent to = ".$email_id;
```

Comment: I think mail is getting shoot but may be your domain is in black list for `sunarctechnologies.com`.

Comment: Actually i have a list of domains, I think not all are in black list.

Comment: Is it site in your production server ? you can also try sending your mail using `SMTP`..

Comment: Why are u not including headers in ur mail , if u have used 4 lines for that. Including headers is necessary for HTML mails

Comment: Its not affecting anything, Even if i include headers at above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check spams/junk mail? Try using http://swiftmailer.org/ to make things easier. You don't need to manually add all the headers your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think its problem with SMTP server of sunarctechnologies.com. Check out the error log of your domain.